# Jquery Dailog not returning the user given value for Confirmation PopUp.

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, dialog, showmodaldialog

Hi I'm using JQUERY Dialog for a confirmation popup. I have a common javascript file, in which i had a function which used to call window.ShowModalDialog. Now from the same function i am calling the jquery dialog, but as it is an asynchronous call, the calling function returns the value(yes/no) without even accepting Values from dialog. How can i return the proper value(yes/no)

Answer (score 0):

If I have correctly understood the problem ...
and if something is wrong, add the example of your code

Try using this pattern:

```
    (function ($, undefined) {
    $.fn.dialog = function (options) {
        options = $.extend({}, $.fn.dialog.options, options);
        return this.each(function () {
            var dialog = $(this);
            dialog.children(".ok").click(function (e) {
                options.ok.call(this, e);
                dialog.close();

            });
            dialog.children(".close").click(function (e) {
                options.close.call(this, e);
                dialog.close();

            });

        });
    };

    $.fn.open = function () {
        this.get(0).showModal();
    };

    $.fn.close = function () {
        this.get(0).close();
    };

    $.fn.dialog.options = {
        ok : function () {},
        close : function () {}
    };
})(jQuery);
```

and using callback

```
var dialog = $(".myDialog").dialog({
        ok : function () {
            alert("ok!!");
        }
    });
```

Do everything you need in callback, but avoid callbackhell.

see [example](https://jsfiddle.net/vLf2bdqo/)